# How to check same Save directive has loaded multiple times in Angular js application

Tags: angularjs

Problem :

I have directive dedicated to show all error messages(404, etc..)

But some time in page , multiple times 404 error occurs several time

I need to get rid of same msg directive from the page.and keep only unique error msges

My approach would be

1 -  load the directive several time using someService
 2 -  check from inside of directive that same error message block 
       directive is already present ? "
 3 - if there , then remove the similar type error message directive.

Question 1 - Is this possible to check the same directive loaded twice in the page ?
Question 2 - If so how to access /how to check?

P.S : currently below code doing nothing.

```
angular.modue('myApp').directive('ErrorBlock',['someInjection',functon(someInjection){
return{
  restrict : E,
  replace :true,
  scope : false,
  link : function(scope , attr, element){
    scope.errorArray = someInjection;
  },
  template : "<div ng-repeat='i in errorArray' ng-bind='i'></div>"    
};}]);
```

Comment: what is `somInjection`? What do you mean by `load directive several times`? Question is not easy to understand

Comment: Some injection is nothing but a service which holds all error messages. When ever  error comes the   setter function of service will be invoked .

Comment: without seeing what you are storing all can suggest is check if it's already in array before adding it again. Need more details if you want a reasonable response